# .htaccess: redirect all to new domain, exclude one folder and allow linking to img/css/js folders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect 'all' pages except one folder ('stayhere').

However the pages in that folder requests several js,img,css files from corresponding js|img|css folders.

The user is redirected correctly, however the requested files are not loading.

How do I fix this? This is my current .htaccess in the root.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(stayhere/.*)$ $1?%1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(js|img|css/.*)$ $1?%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)?\.olddomain\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.nl [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www)?\.olddomain\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.nl [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Perhaps this:
RewriteRule !^(stayhere|js|img|css)($|/) http://newdomain.nl [L,R=301]